# Standard for running SQL queries over HTTP

Tags: sql, postgresql, http, protocols, standards

My client wants to run arbitrary SQL `SELECT` queries on the backend database of our web app, for ad-hoc reporting purposes. The requests will be read-only. Suppose the choice of analysis tool is flexible, but might include Access or psql. Rather than exposing the database on the public Internet, I want to transmit SQL queries over HTTP.

Can I implement a web service that would allow database analysis tools to communicate with the database using a user's web app credentials? E.g. instead of the database connection string starting with `postgres://`, it would start with `https://`. Ideally I'm looking for a [de facto] standard way of doing this.

Related but different/unanswered:

- [Communicate Sql Server over http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098608/communicate-sql-server-over-http)
- [Standards for queries over SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989633/standards-for-queries-over-soap)

Comment: sounds like you need a better client.

Comment: There's actually a significant problem with this: transactions. You'll often need transactions that live longer than a single SQL statement, but you don't want to spread them over multiple client/server interactions for reasons of round trip times, the stateless nature of HTTP meaning clients can just vanish, etc. That's part of why people write middleware that exposes a HTTP API and drives the database. To avoid that you'd probably have to be able to send mini-programs with your HTTP requests for server-side execution - say, as plpgsql functions. No thanks!

Comment: @CraigRinger Good point! I forgot to mention that the queries are read-only `SELECT` statements. I've updated the question.

Comment: @CraigRinger Perhaps this doesn't remove the need for transactions generally, but they won't be needed for our purposes. But since you have pointed out this weakness, I'm starting to think that there's probably no standard for this very reason.

Comment: There are some frameworks that supply a REST interface to a Postgres database. That's probably as close as you can get to "SQL over HTTP", e.g. [pgRest](http://pgre.st/)  or [postgrest](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest) or [sandman](https://github.com/jeffknupp/sandman)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a standard for this.  MK has a point, this sounds like a huge opportunity for a SLQ Injection attack.  Services expose the results of database queries all the time.  They're typically requesting a handful of parameters and exposing a well defined response.  Giving a public user of the service carte-blanche to run any query they want, means that you have to ensure that they don't sneak in a drop database or delete from table query some how.  It can be tricky to defend.  All of that said, I've seen this pattern used for a private service to pool the connections that the database server is aware.  Database connections tend to be pretty expensive.

Comment: I want to note that it might be a good idea to additionally restrict the DB user to only have read access (and only to tables it needs read access to).